# Unable to retrieve users from AD on VMWare vcenter

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi, users, groups, vmware-vcenter

I have added the AD successfully from the vcenter console and also configured the Single Sign On.

[image]

[image: Single Sign On Config]

When I try to retrieve the users from the AD, I first set the domain in the **Users and Groups** tab, then after a while I get the following error:

[image]

So, I attempted to do the same procedure using the Desktop client.

[image]

But, I get the following error.

[image]

**Call "UserDirectory.RetrieveUserGroups" for object "UserDirectory" on vCenter Server "gspsec-vcenter" failed.**

I cannot understand as to what I doing wrong. There is no firewall in between. IN fact, the AD is a VM on the same ESXi that the vCenter is managing.

The version is 5.5.0.5101 Build 1398493.  I restarted the complete appliance after configuring the AD auth as that was recommended

Comment: vCenter version and build number might help narrow this down. And did you actually restart the appliance after configuring the AD auth?

Comment: @RyanBolger - The version is 
5.5.0.5101 Build 1398493. Yes, I restarted the complete appliance after configuring the AD auth as that was recommended.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with Integrated AD Connector. When I changed this to LDAP, this worked fine.